# How to change the string using convert in ms sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query that shows how many hours, minutes and seconds a worker has done for a day:

```
SELECT 
   Employee_Number, CAST([DateTime] as Date) as 'DateTime', 
   MIN([DateTime]) as 'MIN', MAX([DateTime]) as 'MAX', 
   [Hours Worked] = CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR , min([DateTime]),  
   max([DateTime])) % 24 ) AS VARCHAR)  +':'+ CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min([DateTime]), 
   max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, min([DateTime]), 
   max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) + '0' from tblExtract group by Employee_Number, 
   Cast([DateTime] as Date)
```

My problem is I want to convert the Hours worked column in hh:mm:ss. How can I resolve it?

Comment: More information about your question please, what language are you using? why do you want your date in hours? if you explain better you will get more and better answers

Comment: @GaryPerry what I want is to convert the values of Hours Worked column to this format hh:mm:ss. I am using sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, MAX([DateTime]) - MIN(DateTime]), 108) AS [Hours Works]
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
[Hours Worked] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR , min([DateTime]),108)
```

or simply

```
[Hours Worked] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),min([DateTime]),108)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) are the different formats

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this at the palce of hours_worked:-

```
[Hours Worked] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateTime,108)
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Convert() function using the pattern for hh:mm:ss like so:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateTime,108)
```

Other patterns for convert are listed [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp).